# gsutil rsync tries to re-upload everything after migrating source to new storage

Tags: upload, timestamp, cloud, gsutil

I have a substantial (~1 TB) directory that already has a backup on google archive storage. For space reasons on local machine, I had to migrate the directory to somewhere else but now when I try to run the script that was synchronizing it to the cloud (using new directory as source) it attempts to upload everything. I guess the problem lies with timestamps on migrated files, because when I experiment with "`-c`" (CRC comparison) it works fine but just far too slow to be workable (even with compiled CRC).

By manually inspecting timestamps it seems they were copied across well (used `robocopy /mir` for the migration), so what timestamp exactly is upsetting/confusing gsutil..?

I see few ways out of this:

1. Finding a way to preserve original timestamps on copy (I still have the original folder, so that's an option)
2. Somehow convincing gsutil to only patch the timestamps of the cloud files or fall back to size-only
3. Bite the bullet and re-upload everything

Will appreciate any suggestions.

command used for the migration:

```
robocopy SOURCE TARGET /mir /unilog+:robocopy.log /tee
```

Also tried:

```
robocopy SOURCE TARGET /mir /COPY:DAT /DCOPY:T /unilog+:robocopy.log /tee
```

command used for sync with google:

```
gsutil -m rsync -r "source" "gs://MYBUCKET/target"
```

Answer (score 0):

So turns out that even when you try to sync timestamps they end up different:

```
>>> os.stat(r'file.copy')
nt.stat_result(st_mode=33206, ... st_size=1220431L, st_atime=1606987626L, st_mtime=1257521848L, st_ctime=1512570325L)
>>> os.stat(r'file.original')
nt.stat_result(st_mode=33206, ... st_size=1220431L, st_atime=1606987624L, st_mtime=1257521847L, st_ctime=1512570325L)
```

can clearly see that mtime and atime are just fractionally off (later)

trying to sync them:

```
>>> os.utime(r'file.copy', (1606987626, 1257521847))
>>> os.stat(r'file.copy')
nt.stat_result(st_mode=33206, ... st_size=1220431L, st_atime=1606987626L, st_mtime=1257521848L, st_ctime=1512570325L)
```

results in mtime still being off, but if i go a bit further back in time:

```
>>> os.utime(r'file.copy', (1606987626, 1257521845))
>>> os.stat(r'file.copy')
nt.stat_result(st_mode=33206, ... st_size=1220431L, st_atime=1606987626L, st_mtime=1257521846L, st_ctime=1512570325L)
```

It changes, but still not accurate.

However, now after taking it back in time I can use the "`-u`" switch to ignore newer files in destination:

```
gsutil -m rsync -u -r "source" "gs://MYBUCKET/target"
```

script that does fixes timestamps for all files in target:

```
import os

SOURCE = r'source'
TARGET = r'target'

file_count = 0
diff_count = 0

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(SOURCE):
    for name in files:
        file_count += 1
        source_filename = os.path.join(root, name)
        target_filename = source_filename.replace(SOURCE, TARGET)
        try:
            source_stat = os.stat(source_filename)
            target_stat = os.stat(target_filename)
        except WindowsError:
            continue

        delta = 0
        while source_stat.st_mtime < target_stat.st_mtime:
            diff_count += 1
            #print source_filename, source_stat
            #print target_filename, target_stat
            print 'patching', target_filename
            os.utime(target_filename, (source_stat.st_atime, source_stat.st_mtime-delta))
            target_stat = os.stat(target_filename)
            delta += 1

print file_count, diff_count
```

it's far from being perfect, but running the command no longer results in everything trying to sync. Hopefully someone will fine that useful, other solutions are still welcome.